# How do I find what port my rails server is running on and how do I change it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, connection, localhost, port

I'm new to coding and working on a team project where I've just set up rspec from a Github repository and I can't seem to set up my server. I've run db migrate and db drop to see if there were any errors there as seen below. The rails s command is starting the server but it isn't able to connect on localhost:3000

```
rails db:drop
/Users/matthewkennedy/Documents/coderacademy/jfj/jfjapprepository/config/environments/development.rb:4:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Rails::Server
Did you mean?  TCPServer (NameError)
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:234:in `configure'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/Documents/coderacademy/jfj/jfjapprepository/config/environments/development.rb:3:in `<main>'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:570:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/Documents/coderacademy/jfj/jfjapprepository/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:108:in `preload'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:162:in `serve'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:144:in `block in run'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `loop'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `run'
    from /Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Rails db migrate below

```
rails db:migrate
Running via Spring preloader in process 70800
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
<internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:237:in `migrate'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:92:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `each'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:90:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:60:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:40:in `call'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:217:in `block in serve'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:181:in `serve'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:144:in `block in run'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `loop'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `run'
/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
<internal:/Users/matthewkennedy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If anyone could help or give me some pointers, I'd really appreciate it. I am just learning so I would really appreciate help in layman's terms if possible. It will mean the world.

Comment: Just a little tip - the stackoverflow markdown parser requires code fences (\`\`\`) to be the first character on the line. Edited.

Comment: Also the problem is that your rails server isn't actually running. It looks like it's crashing on startup since it can't connect to the db. Check the settings in database.yml and make sure Postgres is running.

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to SO. This (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is really good documentation of how to ask a better question. Also, checkout my answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find process ID with this

```rb
#=> ps aux | grep rails
#=> username 27436   0.0  0.0 408497296   1424 s002  R+    6:01pm   0:00.00 grep .... rails
```

Then use to process ID(ID next to username) to find the port it is running on

```rb
#=> ps -p 25785 -o comm=
#=> puma 5.5.2 (tcp://localhost:3000) [MyRailsApp]
```